# 1px border issue not displaying

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight a specific product on the comparison table. The highlight color is Red but i'm having issues when using 1px, but when i use 2px it works fine but 2px is to big.

Also noticed on this code snippet it does not display RED borders after i have added bootstrap, so attaching a screenshot.
[image]

My goal is to have `Selected Product` to be surrounded by RED 1px border. Also i would not mind any other tips of displaying these types of table.

I have also tried this but did not work: https://muffinman.io/fix-for-chrome-not-rendering-borders/

Also looks like this is not Bootstrap issue, if i remove the BS and use `border-collapse: collapse;` same problem

```css
.table {
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

th:not(:first-child) {
  width: 200px;
}

table,
th {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.border-sides {
  border-right: 1px solid red !important;
  border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

.border-bottom {  
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}

.bg-selected {
  background-color: #b3c2ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>

            <th>
              <div class="text-left">
                <span>Title - Product 1 Test</span>
              </div>
            </th>

            <th class="border border-top">
              <div class="text-left">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Selected Product:</span>
                <span>Title - Product 2</span>
              </div>
            </th>

            <th>
              <div class="text-left">
                <span>Title - Product 2</span>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
            </td>

            <td class="border border-sides">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</button>
            </td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="text-left">
            <td>Description 1</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td class="border bg-selected">N</td>
            <td>N</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="text-left">
            <td class="test">Description 2</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td class="border bg-selected">N</td>
            <td>N</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
            </td>

            <td class="border border-bottom">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</button>
            </td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Also double checked my BS is running first then my CSS or i'm missing something? [image]

Comment: It doesn’t apply a red border after you added bootstrap, because `_borders.scss` applies `border: 1px solid #dee2e6!important;` via the `.border` class selector, and while your rule for `.border-sides` also uses `!important`, it was embedded before the BS styles, so the latter win.

Comment: hm make sense any way to overide BS?

Comment: Make sure your own stylesheet gets embedded after the BS styles …

Comment: For you case https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp, would be much better I guess.

Comment: looks like outline is not going to be an option because i can't select sides of it, and html elements are not in div box

Answer (score 1):

Is this the desired ouput?

**UPDATED**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .table {
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  table,
  .table thead th,
  .table td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  table {
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0 2px 0 0.5px;
  }
  
  th:not(:first-child) {
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  table,
  th {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .table thead th{
    border-top-width: 1px;
  }
  
  .table tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
  }
  
  .table thead th, .table td{
    border-right: none;
  }
  
  .border-sides {
    border-right: 1px solid red !important;
    border-left: 1px solid red !important;
  }
  
  .border-sides + td, .table thead .border-sides + th{
    border-left: none;
  }
  
  .border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid red !important;
  }
  
  .border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
  }
  
  .bg-selected {
    background-color: #b3c2ff;
  }
</style>

<div class="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>

        <th>
          <div class="text-left">
            <span>Title - Product 1 Test</span>
          </div>
        </th>

        <th class="border border-top border-sides">
          <div class="text-left">
            <span class="font-weight-bold">Selected Product:</span>
            <span>Title - Product 2</span>
          </div>
        </th>

        <th>
          <div class="text-left">
            <span>Title - Product 2</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </td>

        <td class="border border-sides">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</button>
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="text-left">
        <td>Description 1</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td class="border bg-selected border-sides">N</td>
        <td>N</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="text-left">
        <td class="test">Description 2</td>
        <td>N</td>
        <td class="border border-sides bg-selected">N</td>
        <td>N</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </td>

        <td class="border border-bottom border-sides">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</button>
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yep looks like this is the closest i can get

Comment: It would have been easier if it wasn't for table. In case of any problem, let me know and don't forget to mark answer correct, when you get done :)

Comment: hm so any thoughts on how differently this could be achieved? :)

Comment: @Marius can you please specify, what change you want exactly?

Comment: just to display the content as on screen shot but also have the ability to get that 1px red box on selected column

Answer (score 0):

You can add `td` for your rule, for example `td.border-top` then it makes it more specific then the BS rule and overrides it